# While Redirecting the url through apache server Data get lost

Tags: apache, http

My Question is this

I redirect the form in

Redirect /formviewer/faces/pages/view/viewform.xhtml

///formviewer/faces/pages/view/viewform.xhtml

in Apache Http Server but the form is not redirecting while doing post request from client Side.

Answer (score 0):

So what *is* it doing?

I rather suspect that its normalising the thing you want to redirect to `///...` and considering it the same.

When looking at redirects, there are three things in my list of 'go-to' tools:

1. `curl -I http://.....` and look at the response and the `Location` header. I use this when installing new redirects  (it avoids following chained redirects and gives me a better view of what is happening at each step.
2. Something like Fiddler or a browsers developer tool. Frankly I'd only use this if `curl` wasn't doing it for me.
3. Enable the `RewriteLog` in Apache... I almost never use this, but for your case it may shed some light.

But let's take a step back: why are you wanting to redirect to a path with and extra `//` prepended (which as I've previously speculated, likely won't work)?